# How to enable anonymous authentication for Kubernetes cluster using kops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, kops

I want to enable anonymous authentication using `kops`, but it's default settings provides the `--anonymous-auth=false` options to `kube-apiserver`:

```
/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=false --apiserver-count=1 --authorization-mode=RBAC --basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
```

How can I change this setting, either for my current cluster or by creating a new cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ssh to master nodes and modify the `kube-apiserver.yaml` in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` and add that flag.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
  - --anonymous-auth=true
```

Then you need to restart your kube-apiserver.

This could vary depending on what you are running in your masters. If something like docker you can do sudo systemctl restart docker or you might need to restart containerd if you are using it instead of docker systemctl restart containerd

Or if you want to just start the kube-apiserver you can do docker restart kube-apiserver or crictl stop kube-apiserver; crictl start kube-apiserver.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I safely restart the API server afterwards? I guess, I needs to restart to use the new configuration? Why do you add the flag under containers? This option only applies to the API server itself?

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation? Does kops use those files to run the containers? In my case, is the kube-apiserver running in a container?

Comment: Yes its running as container from a static file https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/boot-sequence.md#etckubernetesmanifests

Comment: Thank you, it worked flawlessly. I wasn't even required to restart the container, it restarted automatically, why?

Comment: Actually kubelet monitors that directory periodically for any change in yaml